# Why isn't this a valid regular expression?

Tags: javascript, regex, html

This was just working a day ago but now throwing exception.  I've pasted regex into online verifier and it looks good?

What am I missing?

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="nickname" id="nickname" value="Alicia"
       pattern="[\w\s\-\(\)\!\,\.]{3,45}">
```

> Pattern attribute value `[\w\s\-\(\)\!\,\.]{3,45}` is not a valid regular expression: Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid regular expression: `/[\w\s\-\(\)\!\,\.]{3,45}/`: Invalid escape

Thanks for the help!

Casey

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Looks valid to me though Chrome does indeed complain.

In any case, you don't need to escape all those characters within a character class. You should be able to use

```
pattern="[\w\s()!,.-]{3,45}"
```

which seems to work ok for me.

Comment: I am having the same issue with a very simple valid regex (been using for years successfully) and the newest version of Chrome is giving me the same error as OP and a pop up of "Please match the requested format" that is breaking the login page I have.

Comment: Our signup page broke with error "Invalid Escape" on Chrome and "the pattern is not a valid regexp: invalid identity escape in regular expression" in Firefox although that regex was working for months. There was an escaped single quote `\'` in a character class, which was causing the trouble.